# Sharepoint CSOM Authentication issue with .NET Core

Tags: c#, sharepoint, .net-core, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm new to Sharepoint online, and don't have an own account (yet), just an username/password from a client.

Need to build a service that gets the folder structure and archives from Sharepoint. And then allows to up/download archives.

Since the package

> Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

is not compatible with .NET Core, I'm using this github solution that seems to cover the main functionality in an equal way: https://github.com/OneBitSoftware/NetCore.CSOM

I think there is nothing wrong with that so far - but when trying to connect using

> SharePointOnlineCredentials

...I'm getting the error

> PPCRL_REQUEST_E_PARTNER_HAS_NO_ASYMMETRIC_KEY

So I guess there's some account setting missing on the server side? Or am I following a wrong approach? I would have no problem implementing an OAuth access to get a Bearer token, but which API would that be, and how can I register an app for Sharepoint?

My research about API's and this particular error didn't result in anything yet, so I'm reaching out for help here.

Answer (score 6):

Get NuGet package **TTCUE.NetCore.SharepointOnline.CSOM**.16.1.8029.1200.
You can also download an official package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM but it will attach wrong dlls to your project and you would need to change them according to the link from a different answer here - https://rajujoseph.com/getting-net-core-and-sharepoint-csom-play-nice/

Note - Your .NET Core project will compile, but it doesn't mean that it will work on, for example, linux. Those CSOM dlls are not finished and [Microsoft is still working on them](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16585795-support-net-core-with-csom).(for a loooong time...)

Comment: I think this solution is no longer needed as CSOM for .NET Core is already released.

Comment: Please send a liink or name for that package.  I am relying on this one for now.

Comment: @GlennFerrie - The newest package is Pnp.Framework. Or the deprecated one but still working - SharePointPnpCoreOnline. It is not exactly the same as the old one but I would recommend using PnP.

Answer (score 2):

Check the example below:

1. Create a .NET Core console app.
2. Add the references: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.dll`, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable.dll`, and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows.dll`.

   *Note: If the project has references to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`, please remove them.*

   These references can be accessed by installing CSOM library into another project, and then navigating to installed nuget packages in the file directory:
   `c:\Users\user\\.nuget\packages\microsoft.sharepointonline.csom\\(version)\lib\netcore45`
3. Add the code below to the .NET Core 2.0 console application:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string targetSiteURL = @"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx";

            var login = "xxx@xx.onmicrosoft.com";
            var password = "xxx";

            SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, password);

            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);

            ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

            WebCreationInformation wci = new WebCreationInformation();
            wci.Url = "Site1"; // This url is relative to the url provided in the context
            wci.Title = "Site 1";
            wci.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = true;
            wci.WebTemplate = "STS#0";
            wci.Language = 1033;

            var newWeb = ctx.Web.Webs.Add(wci);
            ctx.Load(newWeb, w => w.Title);
            ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Web title:" + newWeb.Title);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

More information: [Getting .NET Core and SharePoint CSOM Play Nice](http://rajujoseph.com/getting-net-core-and-sharepoint-csom-play-nice/)

Comment: Thank you, but where do I found those dll's? I'm on Mac, but I can also try on Windows

Comment: @LZ_MSFT Is it possible to get TokenHelper working with net core? Csom is working for me now but i need Token Helper as I require providing the token.

Comment: Check the solution from here: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Solutions/AspNetCore.Authentication